# CRM 2013 - C# Plugin - Retrieve another entity GUID via lookup

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm creating a plugin that will fire on my custom entity called ContractReview, on the contract review there is a lookup which will hold the sales order associated with it.

In my plugin I can retrieve attributes that are on the form via the lookup. However how do I retrieve the actual GUID of the specific sales order?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, however I'm not sure if it is the best approach;

```
 Entity OrderNumberImage = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["OrderNumberImage"];
 Guid salesGUID = ((EntityReference)OrderNumberImage["new_salesorderlookup"]).Id;
```

Comment: That is a great way to do it. The one thing you may want to check is if the record has that attribute via the Entity.Contains("new_salesorderlookup") to avoid an exception in your plugin if you can't guarantee that it will be set

Comment: Hi @BlueSam, thanks for the clarification, the way the custom entity is designed is that there will always be something inside new_salesorderlookup, and it cannot be deleted. Thanks for the tip though. I only queried wherever it was the best way to do it as the plugin contains the following `var orderNumber = ((Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference)(OrderNumberImage.Attributes["new_salesorderlookup"]));` Therefore wasn't sure if there was a way of getting the GUID from that line of code

Comment: @Sjharrison what is `["OrderNumberImage"]` ? is that entity that contain new_salesorderlookup lookup?